# How do I stream Tweets directly from Twitter into an Amazon Kinesis stream?

Tags: twitter, streaming, amazon-kinesis, tweets

I was hoping to configure an Amazon Kinesis stream to directly consume Twitter data without writing application code. Is this possible? And if so, how?